# MFC Custom Control Not Appearing On Dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, custom-controls

Using Visual Studio 2013, I created a dialog resource using the resource editor. It is a child control with no border and is just a collection of radio buttons, push buttons, and static text. I want to turn this into a custom control in order to place this in several different locations. Let's call this a "Panel".

I then created a regular dialog and using the Toolbox "Custom Control", defined an area for the Panel. The Panel registers itself and has a valid window handle.

I used the following example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521/Creating-Custom-Controls

The parent's DDX gets hit and the _panel is properly instantiated:

```
MyDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX)
   DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CUSTOM_PANEL, _panel)
}
```

I read that I need to override the OnPaint() and OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) methods so the Panel class has these but they are empty. I do not have any custom painting to do as the Panel contains nothing but regular buttons.

**What do I have to include in OnPaint()?**

I also noticed that none of the member buttons are instantiated in the Panel like would normally happen in a dialog's DoDataExchange method.  Instead, I've had to resort to dynamically creating each of the control's inside the Panel's PreSubclassWindow() method:

```
void MyPanel:PreSubclassWindow()
{
   _groupBox.Create(_T("Options"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_GROUPBOX, CRect(11, 11, 112, 231), this, IDC_STATIC_GROUPBOX);

   //... do this for every dialog element??? seems like overkill...

   CWnd::PreSubclassWindow()
}
```

**Why do I need to do this when I've already defined/designed the Panel and each of its controls in the resource editor?**

If I do not do this in the PreSubclassWindow method, nothing will appear on the dialog.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article says override `OnPaint` and `OnEraseBkgnd` if you want to change the functionality. It doesn't say you have to override always.

Just remove `ON_WM_PAINT` and `ON_WM_ERASEBKGND`, remove `OnPaint` and `OnEraseBkgnd` if you don't need them. Or call the base class implementations if you are not making any changes:

```
void MyPanel::OnPaint() { CWnd::OnPaint(); }
BOOL MyPanel::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) { return CWnd::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC); }
```

This will show a blank control with nothing in it, unless you add a child window to `_panel` as you have done in `MyPanel:PreSubclassWindow`

You are adding `_groupBox` to `_panel`. And you are adding `_panel` to the `MyDialog`.

`MyDialog::DoDataExchange(...){DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CUSTOM_PANEL, _panel)}` is needed to invoke `SubclassWindow` for `_panel`. That in turn calls `_groupBox.Create`.

If `MyPanel::OnPaint` and `MyPanel::PreSubclassWindow` are not doing anything `MyPanel` appears as a blank control.

> *... do this for every dialog element??? seems like overkill...*

You can directly add `_groupBox` to the main dialog. But if you want to add specific controls within `MyPanel` then you have to do it manually.

You can also create a child dialog within a main dialog. For example that's how a tab control works.

Comment: Thank you. I can get every element to be drawn through the PreSubclassWindow but your last comment "You can also create a child dialog within a main dialog" led me to an easier solution. I don't know why I thought I was limited to one dialog within a dialog but since I'm not, I can just make the Panel a dialog that can be used in various controls so long I create it dynamically in its parent OnInitDialog rather than rely on its parent DDX to instantiate it.